# find formula in excel

Tags: excel, vba

is it possible to search for a certain text using =find(...... within a specific column like: C1:C2577

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=IF(COUNTIF(C1:C2577,"CertainText")>0, "Present","Absent")

This will tell you if "CertainText" is present or absent in a column

Answer (score 1):

Some VBA code to search for text;

```
Sub SearchRange()
    Range("C1:C2577").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="SOMETHING").Activate
End Sub
```